# what is the solution of this firebase problem?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I saw a tutorial on TAVAC(from youtube). I think I have done my project 99.9% similar but I don't know why my app crash. when I clicked "start quiz" then my apps going to keep stopping.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0hpY.png)

This is my logcat:

```
2021-01-31 19:31:31.743 26745-26745/com.mohammad.quizapp_two E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mohammad.quizapp_two, PID: 26745
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.mohammad.quizapp_two.fragment.QuizFragment.loadQuestion(QuizFragment.java:143)
        at com.mohammad.quizapp_two.fragment.QuizFragment.loadUI(QuizFragment.java:135)
        at com.mohammad.quizapp_two.fragment.QuizFragment.access$200(QuizFragment.java:35)
        at com.mohammad.quizapp_two.fragment.QuizFragment$1.onComplete(QuizFragment.java:111)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-01-31 19:33:07.298 26745-26745/com.mohammad.quizapp_two I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26745 SIG: 9
```

This is my QuizFragment.java:

```
public class QuizFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private NavController navController;

    private static final String TAG = "QuizFragment";

    private TextView quizTitle,questionFeedback,questionText,questionTime,questionNumber;
    private Button optionOneBtn,optionTwoBtn,optionThreeBtn,nextBtn,closeBtn;
    private ProgressBar questionProgress;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    private String quizName;
    private String quizId;

    private List<QuestionModel> allQuestionList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<QuestionModel> questionsToAnswer = new ArrayList<>();
    private int totalQuestionsToAnswer = 5;
    private CountDownTimer countdownTimer;

    private boolean canAnswer = false;
    private int currentQuestion =0;

    private int correctAnswers=0;
    private int wrongAnswers=0;
    private int noteAnswered=0;


    public QuizFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
        //initialize
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //get quizId
        quizName = QuizFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getQuizName();
        quizId = QuizFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getQuizId();
        totalQuestionsToAnswer = QuizFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getTotalQuestions();

        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: "+totalQuestionsToAnswer);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: "+quizId);

        //UI initialize
        quizTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_title);
        optionOneBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_option_one);
        optionTwoBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_option_two);
        optionThreeBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_option_three);
        nextBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_next_btn);
        questionFeedback = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_question_feedback);
        questionText = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
        questionTime = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_question_time);
        questionProgress = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_question_progress);
        questionNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.quiz_question_number);

        //Get all Questions form firebase
        firebaseFirestore.collection("QuizList").document(quizId).collection("Questions")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            allQuestionList = task.getResult().toObjects(QuestionModel.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: "+allQuestionList.get(0).getQuestion());
                            pickQuestions();
                            loadUI();
                        }else{
                            //error
                            quizTitle.setText("Error Loading Data");
                        }
                    }
                });


        optionOneBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        optionTwoBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        optionThreeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void loadUI() {
        //Quiz Data loaded load the UI
        quizTitle.setText(quizName);
        questionText.setText("Load First Question");

        //Enable Options
        enableOptions();

        //Load First Question
        loadQuestion(1);
    }

    private void loadQuestion(int questionNum) {

        currentQuestion = questionNum;
        //Load Question Text
        questionNumber.setText(questionNum+"");
        questionText.setText(questionsToAnswer.get(questionNum-1).getQuestion());

        //Load Options
        optionOneBtn.setText(questionsToAnswer.get(questionNum-1).getOption_a());
        optionTwoBtn.setText(questionsToAnswer.get(questionNum-1).getOption_b());
        optionThreeBtn.setText(questionsToAnswer.get(questionNum-1).getOption_c());

        //Question Loaded, Set Can Answer
        canAnswer = true;

        //Load CountDown
        startTimer(questionNum);
    }

    private void startTimer(int questionNum) {
        //Set Timer text
        final long timeToAnswer = questionsToAnswer.get(questionNum-1).getTimer();
        questionTime.setText(String.valueOf(timeToAnswer));

        //show Timer ProgressBar
        questionProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        countdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeToAnswer*1000,10){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                //Update Time
                questionTime.setText(l/1000+"");

                //progress in percent
                long percent = l/(timeToAnswer*10);
                questionProgress.setProgress((int)percent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //Time Up Cannot Answer

                canAnswer = false;
                countdownTimer.cancel();

                noteAnswered++;
                questionFeedback.setText("Time Up! No answer was submitted.");
                questionFeedback.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary,null));

                showNextBtn();
            }
        };

        countdownTimer.start();
    }

    private void enableOptions() {
        //Show All Options Buttons
        optionOneBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        optionTwoBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        optionThreeBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //enable option Buttons
        optionOneBtn.setClickable(true);
        optionTwoBtn.setClickable(true);
        optionThreeBtn.setClickable(true);

        //Hide Feedback and next Button
        questionFeedback.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        nextBtn.setClickable(false);
    }

    private void pickQuestions() {

        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"PickQuestions",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Collections.shuffle(allQuestionList);

        if(allQuestionList.size()>=totalQuestionsToAnswer){
            questionsToAnswer.addAll(allQuestionList.subList(0,totalQuestionsToAnswer));
            Log.d(TAG, "pickQuestions true: "+questionsToAnswer);
        }else{
            questionsToAnswer.addAll(allQuestionList);
            Log.d(TAG, "pickQuestions false : "+questionsToAnswer);
            totalQuestionsToAnswer =allQuestionList.size();
        }

       /* for (QuestionModel question: questionsToAnswer) {
            Log.d(TAG, "pickQuestions: "+ question.getQuestion());
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.quiz_option_one:
                verifyAnswer(optionOneBtn);
                break;
            case R.id.quiz_option_two:
                verifyAnswer(optionTwoBtn);
                break;
            case R.id.quiz_option_three:
                verifyAnswer(optionThreeBtn);
                break;
            case R.id.quiz_next_btn:
                if(currentQuestion == totalQuestionsToAnswer){
                    submitResults();
                }else{
                    currentQuestion++;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: "+currentQuestion);
                    loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
                    resetOptions();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void submitResults() {
        HashMap<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        resultMap.put("correct",correctAnswers);
        resultMap.put("wrong",wrongAnswers);
        resultMap.put("unanswered", noteAnswered);

        firebaseFirestore.collection("QuizList").document(quizId).collection("Results")
                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).set(resultMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    //Go To Results Page
                    QuizFragmentDirections.ActionQuizFragmentToResultFragment action = QuizFragmentDirections.actionQuizFragmentToResultFragment();
                    action.setQuizId(quizId);
                    navController.navigate(action);
                }else{
                    //Show Error
                    quizTitle.setText(task.getException().getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void resetOptions() {
        optionOneBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.outline_btn_bg,null));
        optionTwoBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.outline_btn_bg,null));
        optionThreeBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.outline_btn_bg,null));

        optionOneBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightText,null));
        optionTwoBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightText,null));
        optionThreeBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightText,null));

        questionFeedback.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //nextBtn.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void verifyAnswer(Button selectBtn) {
        //checkAnswer

        if(canAnswer){

            selectBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            if(questionsToAnswer.get(currentQuestion-1).getAnswer().equals(String.valueOf(selectBtn.getText()))){
                //Correct Answer
                Log.d(TAG, "answerSelected: Correct Answer");
                correctAnswers++;
                selectBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.correct_answer_btn_bg,null));

                questionFeedback.setText("Correct");
                questionFeedback.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }else{
                //Wrong Answer
                Log.d(TAG, "answerSelected: Wrong Answer");
                wrongAnswers++;
                selectBtn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.wrong_answer_btn_bg));
                questionFeedback.setText(String.format("Wrong\nCorrect Ans: %s", questionsToAnswer.get(currentQuestion - 1).getAnswer()));
                questionFeedback.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }

        //Set Can Answer To False
        canAnswer = false;

        //Stop The Timer
        countdownTimer.cancel();

        //Show Next Button
        showNextBtn();
    }

    private void showNextBtn() {
        if(currentQuestion == totalQuestionsToAnswer){
            nextBtn.setText("Submit Results");
        }
        questionFeedback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nextBtn.setClickable(true);

        Log.d(TAG, "showNextBtn: true");
    }
}
```

This is my firebase project photo:

[image: firebase photo]

Answer (score 1):

your error is saying:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

this *always* means that you're trying to access an element in an array and that index doesn't exist (the array could have items or, in your case, it could be completely empty.)

you should make sure that the items you're receiving back from firebase:

1. aren't null

2. aren't empty

where number 2 is likely the cause of your problem here.

in your case, i'd assume that `allQuestionList` is probably an empty list you're trying to access items from.

you're not getting data back from firebase, so your app will crash when trying to access items of an empty array. you have to check:

```
if(!allQuestionList.isEmpty() {
... do the rest
}
```

Comment: allQuestionList = task.getResult().toObjects(QuestionModel.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: "+allQuestionList.get(0).getQuestion());
                            pickQuestions();
                            loadUI();                                                                                           
 thnx for yout answer this is the line but i can not understand what should i do.